# Align ReadMore buttons Horizontally

Tags: html, wordpress, css

I would like to request someone to please guide me on how can i perfectly align the three buttons by the name Read More Horizontally.

Link to Website:
http://advancedspinecareolympia.com/

PSD I am trying to Mimic: https://i.stack.imgur.com/w4mkt.jpg

```
    <p class="heading">Who We Are?</p>
<p class="cdata"><span style="font-weight: bold;">Advanced Spine Care</span> is a health care clinic which focuses on recovery of musculoskeletal complaints in one place. The staff utilizes Chiropractic Mobilization, Massage and Modern Rehabilitative concepts to treat patients.</p>
<p class="cdata">Aaron Fitzpatrick Clinic Director &amp; Chiropractic Physician is also a licensed massage therapist and has worked throughout the west coast and Europe providing his services. He specializes in difficult conditions and only treats those patients he believes he can help.</p>

<div style="margin-top: 80px;">
<div style="width: 33%; float: left;">
<p style="color: #000; font-size: 1.5em; margin-bottom: 30px;">About Us</p>
<p class="cdata">Dr. Aaron will take the time to see the whole puzzle fits together. Dr. Aaron is both a Massage therapist and as well as a Chiropractor and will use tools from his medicine chest to address your complaints in a unique and therapeutic manner.</p>
<p style="margin-top: 50px;"><a class="button-link" href="#">Read More</a></p>

</div>
<div style="width: 33%; float: left;">
<p style="color: #000; font-size: 1.5em; margin-bottom: 30px;">Our Goals</p>
<p class="cdata">Dr. Aaron is committed to searching for the cause of your pain, treating it and when possible teaching you how to avoid it.</p>
<p style="margin-top: 110px;"><a class="button-link" href="#">Read More</a></p>

</div>
<div style="width: 33%; float: left;">
<p style="color: #000; font-size: 1.5em; margin-bottom: 30px;">Our Philosophy</p>
<p class="cdata">Dr. Aaron will take time to see how the whole puzzle fits.
Dr. Aaron is both a Massage therapist and as well as a Chiropractor and will use tools from his medicine chest to address your complaints in a unique and therapeutic manner</p>
<p style="margin-top: 30px;"><a class="button-link" href="#">Read More</a></p>


</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please show us your code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While we are happy to answer any questions, this is not a place to get people to simply write code for you. Please post your code, describe what you've tried and what didn't work, and narrow down your question.

Answer (score 0):

Since the question is not very specific regarding code, I'll give a generic answer based on what one can inspect through Chrome Developer Console on your website.

What I think can help is:

- Make the div containing the three divs (about/goals/philosophy) position:relative
- Make the buttons position:absolute (they will reference the containing div)
- Give them bottom:0 style so they start from the bottom of that containing div - or any other value so they can be offset up.

Answer (score 0):

add this code in your style and apply font-family as your PSD.

```css
.button-link {
  -moz-user-select: none;
  background-color: #138de8;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #20538d;
  border-radius: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) inset, 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  color: #ffffff !important;
  left: 50%;
  padding: 7px 15px;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<p style="margin-top: 30px;"><a class="button-link" href="#">Read More</a>
</p>
```